# How to setup an emulator running API 25 using a build matrix on Travis CI?

Tags: java, android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am attempting to setup Travis CI so that it runs instrumentation tests on an emulator running API 25. Travis runs the tests to completion on API 4/10/19, but fails to startup the emulator for API 25, with the following message:

```
$ echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: Invalid --abi armeabi-v7a for the selected target.
```

The output of `android list targets` shows that the API 19 emulator has a Tag/ABI, whereas the API 25 emulator does not:

```
id: 7 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 4
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a

id: 11 or "android-25"
     Name: Android 7.1.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 25
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

How can I fix this so that the API 25 emulator launches and runs the tests?

The full `.travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
language: android

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools # appears twice as per Travis docs
    - build-tools-23.0.1
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - android-4
    - android-10
    - android-19
    - android-23
    - android-25
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-25

env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-4 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-10 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-19 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-25 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

before_script:
  # Create and start emulator
  - android list targets
  - jdk_switcher use oraclejdk8
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - adb wait-for-device
  - while [[ `adb shell pm path android` == 'Error'* ]]; do sleep 2; done
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: ./gradlew --info connectedAndroidTest

sudo: false
```

Comment: As android list targets is telling you, there is no image with ABI installed on your system, you can try to install correct image with ABI. See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019532/no-abi-error-when-creating-an-android-virtual-device

Comment: My understanding is that the Android emulator needs to be specified as a component in the build script. This matches what's in the Travis CI Docs, albeit with an increase in the Android API level (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#Overview). Travis CI should be installing that for me - shouldn't it?

Comment: You seem to be affected by this issue: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6122

Answer (score 9):

**Note:** emulator version 26.1.4+ versions can introduce or fix bugs. If a reproducible ci build is required, the best option is to download the desired sdk-tools version no via android components.

**Note:** emulator version 26.1.3 is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html) including interesting fixes. I'm busy to revise my answer now:

[image]

Related issue using emulator 26.1.2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45060321/1009132). Relaunch last build [like me](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/andstatus/builds/257416083) to use 26.1.3 and pray, green

> I am attempting to setup Travis CI so that it runs instrumentation
>   tests on an emulator running API 25. Travis runs the tests to
>   completion on API 4/10/19, but fails to startup the emulator for API
>   25...
>
> How can I fix this so that the API 25 emulator launches and runs the
>   tests?

**Update:** I confirmed that ARM ABIs for APIs 23, 25 and 26 are also missing in Android Studio, so:

- It's not a Travis-ci issue. I reproduced it locally as shown in the next image.
- You can use ARM ABI for API-24. I forked your project and it worked in build #6 (next image).
- You can use Google APIs image for API-25 as I explain below using the new `sdkmanager`: [1](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/android-maps-utils/jobs/220859380)
- You can use Google APIs image for API-25 using legacy tools if you know the img name: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28751111/1009132),[2](https://medium.com/@harmittaa/travis-ci-android-example-357f6e632fc4),[3](https://github.com/albodelu/travis-example-android/blob/master/.travis.yml#L53)
- We need to ask to Google or someone else why the ARM ABIs for these APIs are missing.

**Update:** [A related bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62811419) was already reported to Google and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36466682/1009132), please, star it:

> For some reason it's marked as being only available on windows. I'm
>   not sure if this is a problem with ADRT itself or the configuration
>   for this package, but from a quick look it seems like it's probably a
>   problem with adrt itself.

[image]

[image]

---

I'm not sure if the api-25 issue is related but I expect that it will work combining several solutions:

- Use system images with `google_apis` to simplify the build matrix and avoid missing ABIs.
- Use the new `sdkmanager` and `avdmanager` required by the recent Sdk Tools.
- Use the new Trusty images including these tools to simplify the Travis-ci configuration or alternatively use `dist: precise` as explained [here](http://mailchi.mp/travis-ci/ubuntu-trusty-update-2017q2-its-live?e=c1b6bc3f49).

See the links below to working samples using a build matrix that includes Api-25 emulator.

---

I updated the api 23 system image one time on a macbook via Android Studio and appeared a message about the new version was not supported by my computer, so I use the google_apis one.

I offer a possible solution to the [issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6122) commented by Ashish Pathak (I'm also ardock) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42731625/1009132).

I need to update my response to support the new Travis-ci images that comes with new SDK tools.

The new pre-installed Sdk Tools will simplify the solution and reduce the YAML file in size.

---

As announced [in this blog post](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2017-06-19-trusty-updates-2017-Q2) by Carmen Andoh and Dominic Jodoin on 19 Jun 2017:

> Updates are coming to all Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 images
>
> This new generation of Trusty images is already available in
>   production and can be used by adding group: edge in your .travis.yml
>   file:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty

group: edge  # Add this
```

And as explained [here](https://github.com/Karumi/Rosie/pull/89):

> As a bit more information, this new Android image comes with:
>
> Android SDK 25.2.3 build-tools-25.0.2
>
> The new sdkmanager tool - a command line tool that allows you to view,
>   install, update, and uninstall packages for the Android SDK. Replaces
>   the previous android tool, see
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html
>
> Also, the new Android image should be retro-compatible. See the full
>   list of Android SDK components that can be specified in the
>   .travis.yml file, including build-tools-26.0.0-preview.

But they are not using the new avdmanager, I'll try to fix it this weekend.

Alternatively, you can use the previous images by adding `dist: precise`.

---

The lines below are part of [my answer on a related question:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42731625/1009132) prior to the images update:

[Full working sample using constraint-layout codelab repository for Android API level 22 to 25:](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/constraint-layout/builds/220841505)

Two more samples using `sdkmanager` and `avdmanager`:

- [Android Maps Utils library - Google](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/android-maps-utils/builds/220859379)
- [Dexter library - Karumi](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/Dexter/builds/220847349)

**References**

Official documentation related to [Auto-download missing packages with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle)

The [new Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html) options are explained in [Start the Emulator from the Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

`avdmanager` [explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) replaces `android avd` since [SDK tools version 25.3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html)

`sdkmanager` [explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) also enhanced to view and accept all licenses from the command line

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to help. But unfortunately it doesn't give _any_ link to _currently_ working configuration.
I updated .travis.yml as (I think) you suggested in this long post, but emulator still doesn't start, even without "matrix" :-(
See https://travis-ci.org/andstatus/andstatus

BTW, three weeks ago I created an issue in Travis.ci bug tracker "Android emulator doesn't fully start since June 18", and that issue didn't get any reply either :-( https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7981

Comment: You are right but this is a [different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45060321/1009132) that appeared after I created the sample. I'll investigate it this weekend using your project https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/andstatus/builds. This question is about missing arm system image for api-25.

Comment: @yvolk I'll continue next weekend, no luck. Emulator 26.1.2 is bugged. If we use the previous version, the memory issue disappears but the app is not installed for another reason.

Comment: Thank you, I will be happy if you could create a sample working Travis CI configuration for the simplest "Hello world” Android application.

Comment: @yvolk I think the new emulator version fixes it. See the updated response and try it please. I was hired the same day we started this conversation and a release is close. I relaunched last builds and the bug seems gone but I don't remember what includes each build.